# Nodejs Winston Load Transports From Array

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I want to create logger function for my project. I want to load transporters as much as I want from config file. This is my configs;

```js
module.exports = {
  level: "debug",

  transports: ["consoleLogger", "rotateLogger"],

  consoleLogger: {
    type: "console",
    options: {
      stderrLevels: ["error"],
    },
  },

  rotateLogger: {
    type: "rotate",
    options: {
      level: "info",
      filename: "%DATE%.log",
      dirname: "./storage/log/",
      datePattern: "YYYY-MM-DD-HH",
      zippedArchive: true,
      maxSize: "20m",
      maxFiles: "14d",
    },
  },
};
```

And here is my logger file;

```
const winston = require("winston");
const Config = require("gefion-config");
require("winston-daily-rotate-file");

const transports = [];
const loggerConfig = Config.get("logger");

for (let transport of loggerConfig.transports) {
  switch (transport.type) {
    case "console":
      transports.push(new winston.transports.Console(transport.options));
      break;

    case "rotate":
      transports.push(
        new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile(transport.options)
      );
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}

const enumerateErrorFormat = winston.format((info) => {
  if (info instanceof Error) {
    Object.assign(info, { message: info.stack });
  }
  return info;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: Config.get("logger.level"),
  format: winston.format.combine(
    enumerateErrorFormat(),
    Config.get("logger.level") === "development"
      ? winston.format.colorize()
      : winston.format.uncolorize(),
    winston.format.splat(),
    winston.format.printf(({ level, message }) => `${level}: ${message}`)
  ),
  transports,
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Transports array is going empty to winston. Because of that it's not working. I think it is because JavaScript is sync. I tried to use Promise or async-await but I couldn't done it.

How can I fix it?